# I'm playing around with different design patterns in Javascript. This factory has got me confused

Tags: javascript, factory, self-reference

I'm playing around with different JS design patterns, and im trying to modify some samples I've seen out there.  I saw an example of a xhr factory, that had several nested try/catch statements that were nested within eachother.

```
try{
...
}catch(e){
    try{
    ...
    }catch(e){}
}
```

I figured I'd be able to do a self-invoking function.  However It seems to have eluded me as to how it should work.  Does anyone have any advice?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jiggliemon/a7xWq/2/

---

**[Update]**:
http://jsfiddle.net/jiggliemon/b5LaZ/embedded/
Case Closed.

Comment: Not quite sure what the question is here? I tried the example and I wasn't seeing what the problem was?

Comment: the example returns an error "XHR is undefined". and my loop stops at 1 try.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jiggliemon/a7xWq/2/ <--- cleaned it up a little

Comment: Oh I didn't see that happening for me. I got an xmlhttprequest object.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jiggliemon/b5LaZ/embedded/ <--  Got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var XHR = (function(){
    var ins = [
        function(){return new XMLHttpRequest();},
        function(){return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');},
        function(){return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');}
    ],i,tmp;

    return (function tryIns(i){
        i = i || 0;
        while(i < ins.length){
            try{tmp = ins[i]();}
            catch(e){i++; tryIns(i);}
            finally{return ins[i];}
        }
        throw new Error("Your browser doesn\'t support Ajax requests");
    })();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed try loop to:

```
for(var i = 0, l = instances.length; i < l; i ++) {
    try{
        var obj = instances[i].getInstance();
        return instances[i];
    }catch(e){ }
}
```

[Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/a7xWq/5/)